# undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc8

I am getting lots of undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)' linking error's while building our c++ code with the gcc 8.2 on RHEL7, earlier we ware building with the gcc 4.8 and it was building fine.

```
 ~Destructor()
    {
        delete PointerToDynamicallyAllacatedAnotherClassObject;
    }
```

Linker Error: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This symbol is defined in libstdc++.so. Do you compile with g++?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling with g++, I have tried linking libstdc++ but it is not working.

Comment: [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)? (see cases 5 and 6)